# Stripe: Python Connect error regarding brand changes

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Currently integrating Stripe Connect and I keep getting the same error

```
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request ********541g: You must update your Connect branding settings with icon in order to create an account link. You can set the missing fields at https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/connect
```

I have completed everything on Stripe's Dashboard and updated all the branding requirements but I'm now getting this error on my test data. Here is the code below

```
    account = stripe.Account.create(
        country="US",
        type="express",
        capabilities={
            "card_payments": {"requested": True},
            "transfers": {"requested": True},
        },
        business_type="individual",
    )

    return stripe.AccountLink.create(
        account=account['id'],
        refresh_url='https://localhost:3000/',
        return_url='https://localhost:3000/',
        type="account_onboarding",
    )
```

Is there anything else I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

Oh I see the problem. I added print(account) and it shows this below in part of the object

```
   "branding": {
      "icon": null,
      "logo": null,
      "primary_color": null,
      "secondary_color": null
    },
```

Which is odd because I updated that in the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be happening if the settings are present in the Stripe Dashboard here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/connect

Are you using a different account for testing? If so, is the icon set on that account as well?

Comment: Yeah the icon is set there. Not only that, the appearance and business details fields are all filled out. Maybe I need to reach out to support this is weird